# Adjusting the position of a dropdown indicator image

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, navigation

I am trying to add a dropdown arrow on menu items that have submenus and would like to adjust the position of the image so that it is directly below the menu link and centered. How can I adjust the positioning of the image?

Here is my current CSS:

```
nav li.hasChild:after {
    content: url(../images/layout/dropdownOver.png);
}
```

This adds the image directly to the right of the menu item but I'm not sure how to reposition it.

Thanks!

Comment: Position the pseudo element that you are generating with `:after` …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this css instead:

```
nav li.hasChild:after {
    content: url(../images/layout/dropdownOver.png);
    display: block;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
```

Or you can use this:

```
nav li.hasChild {
    background-image: url(../images/layout/dropdownOver.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
}
```

Then in the image you need to put a transparent border around the edge

Answer (score 2):

I came up with 2 different approaches.

The first is much like yours, using `content: url(path_to_image)` directly: [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/upawucA/1/edit?html,css,output)

This is done by adding `display: block;` in both `.menu-item` and it's `:after`, causing a "line-break". `text-align: center;` take cares of centring the image, since it's `display` property is set by default to `inline`.

The other is a little bit different: [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/oguDOjEw/1/edit?html,css,output)

The concept is the same, but now we're using the arrow image as the `background` of `:after` instead of `content`.
I does generates a little bit more of code, but gives you a ton more flexibility when positioning the pseudo-element.